# Trying to read from 14:07 at position 6

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

This works in emulator but in real device give this error

this is my code, give me this error

```
 var date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime!);
          var myDate = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
          notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
              int.parse(myDate.toString().split(':')[0]),
              int.parse(myDate.toString().split(':')[1]),
              task);
```

Comment: Error context seems  doesn't included, can you include sample data that will reproduce the same error ?

Comment: The application will work and the time type 12 hours  like 3.07Pm its work but 24 hours means like  15.07pm اit doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `int.tryParse`

```dart
notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
    int.tryParse(myDate.toString().split(':')[0]) ?? 0,
    int.tryParse(myDate.toString().split(':')[1].substring(0, 2)) ?? 0, task);
```

If it fails on parser, you will get 0:0

Comment: thank you , its work can you explan the code how it work

Comment: when the output is `15.07pm` , I am creating another substring , `07` , here I am removing pm . If something ever happen while parsing, it will provide 0